# Problems using the VTK camera function elevation

Tags: camera, render, vtk, elevation

I have to implement some kind of flythrough via VTK (through a skull for example) and keyboard navigation.

My idea is to manipulate my camera so that i can move arround the object. In VTK you can manipulate the camera with functions like Azimuth, Elevation, Roll and so on.

Every function works fine and does what it is supposed to do except the Elevation function.
This one is supposed to move my camera up or down arround the focal point.
That's what it actually does until it reaches approximately 90 degrees in the up or down direction. As soon as it reaches the 90 degrees it kind of turns my object arround in a unlogical way. It's hard to explain but it does not continue to elevate arround my focal point.

I've already looked how the function is implemented but i can't realy find a reason why it behaves like that.

Does anyone have an idea what possibly causes this problem?

Answer (score 3):

It is necessary to recompute the ViewUp vector to force it to be perpendicular to the camera focalpoint vector.

Call the method OrthogonalizeViewUp() of your camera, after you have applied your values to Azimuth and Elevation.

```
myVtkCamera->OrthogonalizeViewUp();
```

Comment: Thank you I was having issues with `->Elevation` flipping the camera view when going past 180 deg and this fixed my issues. Setting to VTK camera has proved to be a real pain.